# ModelMapper takes to much time to map entity to DTO object

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, modelmapper

I want to ask you something. I'm facing some issues when a have to map an entity object to DTO object using org.modelMapper.

The thing is that for my teammates everything is working correctly, it takes about 4-5 seconds, but for me it's like 10-20 minutes or even more.

We have so many nested objects in the entities and in the DTO's but they should have this problem too. The thing is that only happens to me. I tried with another computer which is faster but it happens also.

Here are some details of the project:

- Java 11 Spring Boot
- PostgreSQL for the database
- We open a tunnel connection for the database
- We use the same VPN for the internet connection

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: This is something i faced too. If you are connecting to db over vpn then its too slow a connection. Rather you should have your application hosted on the server in same lan where postgres is deployed.

Comment: The thing is that my teammates don't have this problem, and they use VPN as I do...

Comment: What about creating breakpoints to understand which part of your code execution takes the most time?

Comment: I did it, it's when I convert the entity object to a dto, first time I thought that it was when I get the information from the database but that works really fast. The problem is when I map the entity to de DTO

Comment: Actually, I don't think that someone will help you here, because it's too little information to give you an answer, and you cannot provide it all. I meant that you can create breakpoints inside generated by MapStruct class and see which part of mapping is the slowest.

Comment: Solution found! It was because of the Java version, I was using Java 15, and I don't know why it doesn't work well with modelMapper... With Java 11 works perfectly!